# Why is this NoClassDefFoundError being thrown when the class exists?

Tags: java, generics, netbeans

I've tried to create a generic Observable class that I can use in my program:

```
public class GeoGolfObserver<T> extends Observable
{
    public GeoGolfObserver()
    {
        super();
    }

    public void passObject(T object)
    {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(object);
    }
}
```

It is created using:

```
GeoGolfObserver<Cache> cacheObserver = new GeoGolfObserver<Cache>(); // [1]
cacheObserver.addObserver(this);
new CreateCache(cacheObserver).setVisible(true);
```

This is passed in to the constructor of the CreateCache class:

```
public CreateCache(GeoGolfObserver<Cache> cacheObserver) {
    initComponents();
    bindList();
    this.cacheObserver = cacheObserver;
}
```

However, the line marked [1] above throws an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Common/GeoGolfObserver
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED**

The problem was fixed by simply telling netbeans to do a clean rebuild of my application. Thanks for your comments guys.

Answer (score 3):

One of your classes is not found in the classpath. Specifically, `GeoGolfObserver`, if I understand your error correctly.

Check that you have valid references to all of your classes, and respective JAR/class files for them in your classpath.

Comment: maybe he meant the Observable interface, which comes with javah